# How do I style an array item the user put in using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, dom

I'll try to explain my problem as best as I can, but I might use the wrong terminology as I'm still fairly new to coding.

So I'm making a website that mimics a coffee shop for a personal project; the JS I wrote is able to search up coffees from an array and display them based on what the user inputs (the user goes into a form, they pick a roast setting and all the coffees under that roast pop up, they can just search it by name, etc). There's also an option for the user to make their own coffee, where they can type in their own name and add their roast. After that, it'll be added to the existing array and it'll pop up on the menu.

What I wanted to do was style the user-inputted coffee differently than the rest of the menu items so people can tell that this item is a new addition, like by putting an image next to it with a "new" icon for example, but I don't know how to target that user item specifically. I'd rather not take it out of the array, if possible.

Styling with JS and JS in general are not my strong suits, so if anybody could help me with this problem, that would be amazing. I'll try to include a minimal code example here (I don't know if this is enough to determine the issue):

```
    /* Displays Coffees on page  */

function renderCoffee(coffee) {

    var html = '<div class="col col-padding">';
    html += '<div class="noId">' + coffee.id + '</div>';
    html += '<p>' + coffee.name + '&nbsp;' + coffee.roast + '</p>';
    html += '</div>';

    return html;
}

/* Loops through the coffees array  */

function renderCoffees(coffees) {
    var html = '';
    for(var i = coffees.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        html += renderCoffee(coffees[i]);
    }
    return html;
}

/* Updates Data */

function updateCoffees(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // don't submit the form, we just want to update the data
    var selectedRoast = roastSelection.value;
    var filteredCoffees = [];
    coffees.forEach(function(coffee) {
        if (coffee.roast === selectedRoast) {
            filteredCoffees.push(coffee);
        }
    });
    tbody.innerHTML = renderCoffees(filteredCoffees);
} 

    /* Coffees Array  */
    
    // from http://www.ncausa.org/About-Coffee/Coffee-Roasts-Guide
    var coffees = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Light City', roast: 'light'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Half City', roast: 'light'},
        {id: 3, name: 'Cinnamon', roast: 'light'},
        {id: 4, name: 'City', roast: 'medium'},
        {id: 5, name: 'American', roast: 'medium'},
        {id: 6, name: 'Breakfast', roast: 'medium'},
        {id: 7, name: 'High', roast: 'dark'},
        {id: 8, name: 'Continental', roast: 'dark'},
        {id: 9, name: 'New Orleans', roast: 'dark'},
        {id: 10, name: 'European', roast: 'dark'},
        {id: 11, name: 'Espresso', roast: 'dark'},
        {id: 12, name: 'Viennese', roast: 'dark'},
        {id: 13, name: 'Italian', roast: 'dark'},
        {id: 14, name: 'French', roast: 'dark'},
    ];

/* NEW COFFEE FUNCTION */

var search2 = document.getElementById('search-2');
var buildText = document.getElementById("submit");
var searchRoast2 = document.getElementById("roast-selection-2");
buildText.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var coffeeInput = search2.value
    var pickRoast2 = searchRoast2.value
    var newCoffee = {
        name:coffeeInput,
        roast:pickRoast2,
    }

    coffees.push(newCoffee)

    tbody.innerHTML = renderCoffees(coffees)

    console.log(coffees)
})
```

I'd appreciate any help/solutions I can get. :)

Comment: Give the user-inputted items a different CSS class.

Comment: Hi Rhiannon H!  To better facilitate getting answers for your question, can you put a [mcve] in the body of the question?  Please note that [linking to your code on a third party site is not sufficient for a properly formed question on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).  Thanks!

Comment: Please post a [mcve] here, not a link to a github project. This question will last forever, but you're going to update your project when you get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could consider is adding a boolean property to the array of coffee objects and call it something like `userOption`. Set user inputted options to `true` and the default options to `false`, like so:

```
var coffees = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Light City', roast: 'light', userOption: false},
    {id: 2, name: 'Half City', roast: 'light', userOption: false},
    {id: 3, name: 'Cinnamon', roast: 'light', userOption: false},
    {id: 4, name: 'Blue Bottle', roast: 'medium', userOption: true},
    {id: 5, name: 'Pike Place', roast: 'dark', userOption: true},
]
```

Then, run a `filter` method on the object array to only return the options that are user-generated:

```
const userCoffees = coffees.filter(coffee => coffee.userOption)

const defaultCoffees = coffees.filter(coffee => !coffee.userOption)
```

If you use this method, you can render the user coffees with different styling rules than the default coffees.

Comment: I feel like this is really close to the answer I'm looking for. I took you advice and added the const's and put them in functions filterDefault(coffees) and filterUser(coffees). I also added user options to each coffee...but now I'm struggling to implement this code in a way to where I can style it. Do I need to rewrite the renderCoffee function and pass filterUser in as a parameter? Do I need to write another separate renderCoffee function that does the same thing but with filterDefault? I've been messing with it for awhile on my own; I'm sorry if this seems redundant or silly to ask.

Comment: Please link to a codesandbox with the new code -- happy to take a look and see what I can do to help you out :)